# How can i find php.ini in wordpress directory?

Tags: php, wordpress, path, configuration

i need config the error_log parameter and i have no idea where is wordpress.

[image]

that is my directory in wordpress

Comment: If you have access to the cli, run phpinfo()

Comment: Why? The php.ini does not belong into wordpress directory, it belongs the php/webserver configuration. Do you mean the config.php for wordpress?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Environment variables in Wordpress wp-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9300950/using-environment-variables-in-wordpress-wp-config)